# Path objects in projective model structure

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

I want to know how path objects look like in the presheaf category $[\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\text{op}}, \text{Gpd}]$. Note that this category is just groupoids equipped with involutions. So, I start with path objects in Gpd whose one explicit characterisation is, being given a groupoid $G$, $PG$ is the groupoid whose objects are triples $(g\in G, (g',g'),\alpha: (g,g)\cong (g',g'))$  and a map between $(g,(g',g'),\alpha)$ and $(h,(h',h'),\beta)$ is just a map in $G$ between $g$ and $g'$. Now, you can factor the diagonal map by $U$ followed by $V$ where $U(g) = (g,(g,g),id)$ and $U(f) = f$ and $V(g,(g',g'),\alpha) = (g',g')$ and $V(f) = \beta\circ (f,f)\circ \alpha^{-1}$. Now, being given an involution on $G$ denoted $i$, I equipped $PG$ with the following involution denoted $i'$ by setting $i'(g,(g',g'),\alpha) = (i(g), (i(g'),i(g')), i(\alpha))$ and $i'(f) = i(f)$. Note that the previous maps $U$ and $V$ are compatible with the involutions, ie $U\circ i = i'\circ U$ and similarly for $V$ and $V$ is a projective fibration (it's just an isofibration). But I haven't succeed to prove that $U$ is a projective trivial cofibration. Any idea ?

Best

Comment: I put in the proper LaTeX maths mode - I don't know why you'd put single symbols like $\cong$ and $\circ$ in maths mode and not the rest of the expression, but it looked weird to me.

Comment: Well, my students really like to write stuff like "`Let x $<$ y and suppose ...`". It's horrible.

Comment: yes, I apologize for this ugly liberal use of LaTeX. Thanks David.